# Conditional Formatting based of date other the Today

Tags: excel, date, conditional-formatting

I work with a data base that has date of when a approval expire and those date can be any thing from  30 days from now or 5-8 years. The cell is already conditionally formatted `=IF(G3<TODAY(),1,0)` to turn Red if the date in the box is before today date. The formatting I want add to make the cell turn yellow if it is days out from the date it the box as to give me a quick reference to see what one are to expire soon and give them a heads up. All the formatting on this workbook was done by co-worker before I got it and that coworker no longer works here. I am working with Excel 2010.

Comment: Why not just add the appropriate conditional formats?  Just use the same logic that is being used in the CF that you have.  The formula you have can be simplified to `=G3<TODAY())`

Comment: I need the formatting for yellow to be set for 30 day out from the expiration date in the cell. so say the date is 10/30/2017 the cell would turn yellow when I look at it on 10/1.

Comment: 30 days or end-of-month?

Comment: What formula have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you want to chage the format, then go to *Conditional formatting rules*, then New Rules and select "*use a formula to determine wich cells to format*".
You have to insert these three rules:

```
Out of date (red) => $A$1-TODAY()<0
Warning (yellow) => $A$1-TODAY()<=10
Good (green) =>$A$1-TODAY()>10
```

where A1 contains the date when the data will expires and 10 is the number of days to the expires data when you have to give a quick.
It is important that you mark the flag "Stop if true" inside the *Conditional formatting rules* window.